# Combing these two mySQL queries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to combine my main query with a subquery:

**Current query (which works):**

```
SELECT *,(SELECT SUM(shift_length)FROM overtime_list
WHERE overtime_list.user_ID = users.user_ID AND overtime_list.date > '$totalovertimedays') AS overtime_total FROM availability_list
JOIN users ON users.user_ID = availability_list.user_ID
JOIN stations ON users.station_ID` = stations.station_ID
WHERE availability_list.date = '$date' AND type = '$type'
ORDER BY overtime_total ASC
```

*($date and $type are vars filled in by PHP)*

**The query I want to insert this as a sub-query:**

```
SELECT role_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(users_roles.role_ID) AS roles FROM users
JOIN users_roles ON users.user_ID = users_roles.user_ID
GROUP BY users.users_ID
```

**I got this far - but I cant seem to get the GROUP BY to work, so it doesnt list them correctly:**

```
SELECT *,(SELECT SUM(shift_length)FROM overtime_list
WHERE overtime_list.user_ID = users.user_ID AND overtime_list.date > '$totalovertimedays') AS overtime_total FROM availability_list
JOIN users ON users.user_ID = availability_list.user_ID
JOIN `stations` ON `users`.`station_ID` = `stations`.`station_ID`,
(SELECT role_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(users_roles.role_ID separator ', ') AS roles FROM users JOIN users_roles ON users.user_ID = users_roles.user_ID GROUP BY users.user_ID) AS roles
WHERE availability_list.date = '$date' AND type = '$type'
ORDER BY overtime_total ASC
```

**availability_list table:**

```
 +----------+---------+
 |  user_ID | user    |
 +----------+---------+
 |        1 |   Smith |
 +----------+---------+
 |        2 |   Jones |
 +----------+---------+
 |        3 |   Greg  |
 +----------+---------+
```

**overtime_list table:**

```
 +----------+----------------+------------+
 |  date    | shift_length   |   user_ID  |
 +----------+----------------+------------+
 |  1/1/11  |   5            |      1     |
 +----------+---------+------+------------+
 |  1/2/11  |   5            |      2     |
 +----------+---------+------+------------+
 |  1/6/11  |   2            |      2     |
 +----------+---------+------+------------+
 |  1/8/11  |   5            |      1     |
 +----------+---------+------+------------+
 |  1/12/11 |   2            |      1     |
 +----------+---------+------+------------+
```

**users_roles table:**

```
 +----------+---------+
 |  user_ID | roles   |
 +----------+---------+
 |        1 |   Admin |
 +----------+---------+
 |        2 |   Staff |
 +----------+---------+
 |        2 |   Admin |
 +----------+---------+
 |        2 |   Super |
 +----------+---------+
 |        1 |   Other |
 +----------+---------+
```

**So the result would be:**

```
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |  user_ID | user    |   roles                    |  overtime_total  |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        1 |   Smith |    Admin, Other            |        12        |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        2 |   Jones |    Staff, Admin, Super     |        7         |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        3 |   Greg  |                            |  null (or zero)  |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: When asking a question like this it is generally a good idea to include an example in the form of - given this data I would like to retrieve the following result. The more effort you put into asking your question the better the answers.

Comment: ok - thanks nnichols - will do that next time

Comment: Can there be multiple entries in overtime_list for the same user on the same date? I think my query will result in the Cartesian product of the two subsets from users_roles and overtime_list.

Comment: i just edited my original question for you to help provide more info. There should be only one overtime shift per date

Comment: Good job on updating your question. It is much better now. I am hoping that the dates in overtime_list are of type DATE and not the string values that you have in your example.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work -

```
SELECT users.*,
    SUM(overtime_list.shift_length) AS overtime_total,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users_roles.role_ID) FROM users_roles WHERE users.user_ID = users_roles.user_ID) AS roles
FROM availability_list
INNER JOIN users
    ON users.user_ID = availability_list.user_ID
INNER JOIN `stations`
    ON `users`.`station_ID` = `stations`.`station_ID`
INNER JOIN overtime_list
    ON overtime_list.user_ID = users.user_ID
    AND overtime_list.date >= '$totalovertimedays'
WHERE availability_list.date = '$date'
AND type = '$type'
GROUP BY users.user_ID
ORDER BY overtime_total ASC
```

Comment: oh no - theres a bug! with my query, if there were no records which (overtime_list.date >= '$totalovertimedays') return, the sum count was 0, but the user still displays. But in your answer, if there are no records where (overtime_list.date >= '$totalovertimedays'), then the user doesnt display at all!

Comment: i've edited my original question to show the user with no overtime records for clarification

Comment: yay - I fixed it! just needed to change "INNER JOIN overtime_list" to "LEFT JOIN overtime_list" - thanks again nnichols

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest re-thinking the result you want. You're asking for this:

```
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |  user_ID | user    |   roles                    |  overtime_total  |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        1 |   Smith |    Admin, Other            |        12        |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        2 |   Jones |    Staff, Admin, Super     |        7         |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
```

However, it's more common for a query to return this:

```
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |  user_ID | user    |   roles                    |  overtime_total  |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        1 |   Smith |    Admin                   |        12        |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        1 |   Smith |    Other                   |        12        |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        2 |   Jones |    Staff                   |        7         |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        2 |   Jones |    Admin                   |        7         |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        2 |   Jones |    Super                   |        7         |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
```

It's then fairly simple to collect together the rows created for each user, and thus collect all their roles. (You may feel it's easier if you first sort by `user_ID`, and detect when the user_ID changes.)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the `GROUP_CONCAT` to group all the role-names together, this might work:

```
SELECT users.user_ID, users.user, 
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users_roles.roles) 
      FROM users_roles
      WHERE users_roles.user_ID = users.user_ID) as roles,
   (SELECT SUM(shift_length)
      FROM overtime_list
      WHERE overtime_list.user_ID = users.user_ID 
        AND overtime_list.date > '$totalovertimedays') AS overtime_total,
   FROM availability_list
     JOIN users ON users.user_ID = availability_list.user_ID
     JOIN stations ON users.station_ID` = stations.station_ID
     WHERE availability_list.date = '$date' AND type = '$type'
     ORDER BY overtime_total ASC
```

Using this 2nd sub-query seems to to make this query even less efficient than it already is, so I'd be wary of using this in a high-volume system. If you're just reading a few thousand entries only a few times a day, you'll never notice a delay.